# Font Conversion online tool from TTF to js

Tags: javascript, jquery, truetype, typeface

I am working on jquery and easyUI. I am converting normal text in to 3d text  using three.js. I need to use custom font in .js format. I am trying typeface.js site  from past 4 days, but it is not working. Please can anybody suggest me how to convert ttf to .js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try http://cufon.shoqolate.com. This is an alternative site.

Comment: This website is closed. Please open link to check. Need new solution. Please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

This converter works with three.js 
http://gero3.github.io/facetype.js/